# Python dec to bin from file to file

Tags: python, binary, decimal

I've got some problems with python script. I'm not that good at this language, as I'm doing something for my friend.

The code is working but output is straight up weird. Some random things instead of binary numbers.

Here's the code:

```
def decToBin(n):
    wynik = ""
    while n > 0:
        wynik = str(n % 2) + wynik
        n = n / 2
    return wynik
print("zamiana liczb z systemu dziesietnego na binarny")
with open('program.txt', 'r') as plik: # otwieramy plik do odczytu
    for line in plik:
        x=int(line)
        with open('wyniki.txt', 'w') as plik1:
            plik1.write(decToBin(x))
        plik1.close()
plik.close()
```

And here's the link to the script: 
[repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SerenePastelLegacysystem)

/edit
OKay, figured it out, here's the code now:

```
def decToBin(n):
wynik = ""
while n > 0:
    wynik = str(n % 2) + wynik
    n = int(n/2)
return wynik
plik1=open('wyniki.txt', 'w')
print("zamiana liczb z systemu dziesietnego na binarny")
with open('program.txt', 'r') as plik:  # otwieramy plik do odczytu
    for line in plik:
    x = int(line)
    plik1.write(decToBin(x)) 
    plik1.write("\n")  
plik1.close()
```

Comment: Can you please put your code into a proper code block? It is really hard to read this way. On a side note, you should remove `plik.close()` and `plik1.close()`, since your `with`-statements already take care of that.

Comment: Please refactor this code into a [mcve] that doesn't require the reader to have a file named "program.txt", and which doesn't create new files on their system. Something like "I tried `print(decToBin(3))` and expected to get '111', but I got [actual output] instead" would be good.

Comment: Can you show an example of the input file please? Also, an example of the "random things" in the output?  As an aside, the indentation of your code is "off" and makes it hard to read, since python syntax relies on indentation it's more important than other langs such as java.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: there already is something that does precisely what you're trying to do, so it would be wise and effective to just use it:

```
for char in text:
     bin(int(char))
```

The problem in your code, I guess, is that you're using Python 3.x, where standard division between integers returns a float (as of [https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/][PEP-0238]).
Here is a suggestion on how you should change your function for it to work. You can check it against the built-in *bin* function:

```
def decToBin(n):
    wynik = ""
    while n > 0:
        wynik = str(n % 2) + wynik
        n = n // 2
    return wynik
```

Comment: Ok, works better but it converts only the last number in source file now

Comment: Try changing 

`with open('wyniki.txt', 'w') as plik1:`

with

`with open('wyniki.txt', 'a') as plik1:`

. Also I slightly edited my previous reply, namely I just changed `int(n / 2)` with `n // 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it for a sample of the text- Python will not convert chars to ints in the way that Java/C may.  Instead, you would get the ordinal value, and then convert this to a binary number

```
def to_bin(c):
    bin_rep = bin(ord(c))
    print bin_rep   # for testing
    return bin_rep  # can be written to a file here or not...

text = "Hello there"
for each_char in text:
    to_bin(each_char)
```

I think this approach is worth trying with a sample of your input file, and then refactor to do it as a file r/w.

To do this with the file, try this:

```
write_str = ""
with open('program.txt', 'r') as plik: # otwieramy plik do odczytu
    for line in plik:
        for each_char in line:
            write_str += str(to_bin(each_char))
with open('wyniki.txt', 'w') as plik1:
    plik1.write(write_str)
    plik1.close()
plik.close()
```

If you want the order of the bytes reversed, the entire file could be reversed or change 
    write_str += str(to_bin(each_char)) 
to 
    write_str = str(to_bin(each_char)) + write_str

Comment: Ok, but I need to do to this by algorithm, like with while or something, that's the problem

Comment: see amended ans- using a nested for loop. You may choose to write to the file but I think it is better (for several reasons) to write at the end- otherwise it'll slow up the program a lot